# Keeping hitting API to refresh details

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs

I'm creating a ReactJS component that will get the current price of bitcoin, ethereum and golem using an API. So far, I've been able to retrieve the data and output it in the render function. However, I want the price to keep refreshing rather than hitting the API once and then changing the state. This is my current component

```
class PriceChecker extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      priceBtc: '00:00',
      priceEth: '00.00',
      priceGol: '00:00'
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    fetch("https://coinmarketcap-nexuist.rhcloud.com/api/btc").then(request => request.json()).then(request => this.setState({priceBtc: request.price.usd}))
    fetch("https://coinmarketcap-nexuist.rhcloud.com/api/eth").then(request => request.json()).then(request => this.setState({priceEth: request.price.usd}))
    fetch("https://coinmarketcap-nexuist.rhcloud.com/api/gnt").then(request => request.json()).then(response => this.setState({priceGol: response.price.usd}))
  }
  render(){
     return (
      <div className="price">
      <h1 className="headline-pr">Current Prices</h1>
      <div className="price-container">
        <div className="price-card">
          <span>Bitcoin Price</span>
          <h1>${this.state.priceBtc}</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="price-card">
          <span>Ethereum Price</span>
          <h1>${this.state.priceEth}</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="price-card">
          <span>Golem Price</span>
          <h1>${this.state.priceGol}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Is there any way i can keep hitting the API or at least refresh the price every 10 seconds or so?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the code in `componentDidMount` inside a `setInterval`

```
let timeinterval;
componentDidMount(){
    timeinterval = setInterval(function() {
        fetch("https://coinmarketcap-nexuist.rhcloud.com/api/btc").then(request => request.json()).then(request => this.setState({priceBtc: request.price.usd}))
        fetch("https://coinmarketcap-nexuist.rhcloud.com/api/eth").then(request => request.json()).then(request => this.setState({priceEth: request.price.usd}))
        fetch("https://coinmarketcap-nexuist.rhcloud.com/api/gnt").then(request => request.json()).then(response => this.setState({priceGol: response.price.usd}))
    }, 1000);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(timeinterval);
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused as to where to put the let time interval declaration

Comment: You can either declare it outside of your component or as member of your component in the `constructor()` and access it with `this.timeinterval` I guess. Not sure which one is best though.